# Why does the purge command not work? (no errors) discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Bot #1 (Eulogist Official Bot)

[image: bot #1 (not working)]

Bot #2 (Prosser Recoveries)

[image: bot2 #2 (working)]

So here we have two of my bots. the purge command is:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../config.json");
module.exports = {
  config: {
    name: "purge",
    description: "Purges messages",
    usage: " ",
    category: "moderation",
    accessableby: "Moderators",
    aliases: ["clear", "prune"],
  },
  run: async (prosser, message, args) => {
    message.delete();
    let hrps = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`**Command:** ${config["Bot_Info"].prefix}purge`)
      .setDescription(
        `**Aliases:** /prune, /clear\n**Description:** Delete a number of messages from a channel. (limit 100)\n**Usage:**\n${config["Bot_Info"].prefix}purge 20\n${config["Bot_Info"].prefix}bc`
      )
      .setColor();
      let done = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`Purged \`${args[0]}\` message(s). ✅`)
      .setColor(`${config["Embed_Defaults"].EmbedColour}`);
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.reply("Doesn't look like you can do that");
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(hrps);
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]).then(() => {
      message.channel
        .send(done)
        .then((msg) => msg.delete({ timeout: 1000 }));
    });
  },
};
```

These two bots have the same purge command but only one of the bots command works. (i've checked perms & invited to different servers).

Has anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Can you make sure that the module is being  executed by logging something after the `run` line?

Comment: @Radnerus yup just logged it and i got no console log so it isn't being executed. no clue why though as nothing has changed from my other bot

Comment: Oh, then make sure the command handler is working.

Comment: all the other commands work perfectly @Radnerus which is why i have no clue what is wrong with it

Comment: Are you sure you are using this module in the command handler?

Comment: i'm confused as to what you mean using it. i have other commands in the folder where this is located and it works. @Radnerus

Comment: for some odd reason only that one command in that whole folder is not getting loaded. every other command works. i just moved the command file to a different folder and it works fine. this has left me really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! All i done was moved the js file to a different command folder and it suddenly worked.